# How to get result/data from procedure from SQL command line

Tags: sql, oracle

looking for what causing to error message below:

```
[Error] Execution (4: 5): ORA-06550: line 4, column 5: PLS-00306:
wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ALLOC_DAY_GRAPH_KTL'
ORA-06550: line 4, column 39: PLS-00363: expression '01-Oct-2012'
cannot be used as an assignment target ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
'ALLOC_DAY_GRAPH_KTL' ORA-06550: line 4, column 5: PL/SQL: Statement
ignored
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I need to view data for certain date (date_parameter).

Comment: Is `reports.rep_type` a cursor type?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE package reports
as type rep_type is ref cursor;
end reports;
/

Comment: it looks like package?

Comment: it looks like rep_type is ref cursor

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

If this is a package existing in a db, you could write a simple pl sql procedure block which calls the required procedure in the package and save it a s a sql script. It can then be called from the sqlplus commandline using @filename.sql

Comment: it's existing one and I'd like to view result in sql

Comment: can you give example of this procedure

Comment: SET SERVEROUTPUT ON                
    BEGIN
    prackage_name.procedure_name(arguments);
    END;




save the above with your corresponding package and procedure name as  a sql file and invoke the script in sqlplus as @sqlfilename.sql

Answer (score 0):

This could be a simple way:

**setup:**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE reports AS
  2      TYPE rep_type IS REF CURSOR;
  3  END reports;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure testCursor(pIn in number, pCursOut in OUT reports.rep_type) is
  2  begin
  3      open pCursOut for
  4          select 1 as one,
  5                 'something' as text,
  6                 pIn as parameter
  7          from dual;
  8  end;
  9  /

Procedure created.
```

**call:**

```
SQL> variable vCur refCursor
SQL> exec testCursor(999, :vCur);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :vCur

       ONE TEXT       PARAMETER
---------- --------- ----------
         1 something        999

SQL>
```

If you are not in SQLPlus, you may need a plSQL block:

```
declare
    vCur reports.rep_type;
begin
    testCursor(999, vCur);
    /* code to use the cursor */
end;
/
```

In this case you need to write some code to do whatever you need with the cursor returned by the procedure.

Comment: try to run: variable vCur refCursor

Comment: gives erro: [Error] Execution (1: 1): ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: looks like can't recognize refCursor

Comment: the end reports should come after the procedure definition inside the packages right?

Comment: not sure I understand: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Comment: Where are you running from? this is for sqlPlus

Comment: If you want to use toad you need a plsql block; in this case you can not simply print the cursor, but you need some code to handle it

Comment: TOAD Editor window

Comment: Now it runs with different error: [Error] Execution (8: 5): ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ALLOC_DAY_GRAPH_KTL'
ORA-06550: line 4, column 39:
PLS-00363: expression '01-Oct-2012' cannot be used as an assignment target
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ALLOC_DAY_GRAPH_KTL'
ORA-06550: line 4, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: Here is actual procedure: in my case i have two dates for input: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REPORTING_TCO.Alloc_day_graph_KTL (
Alloc_day_graph_KTL_cursor IN OUT Reports.rep_type,
S_Date IN system_days.daytime%TYPE,
E_Date IN system_days.daytime%TYPE)
AS

Comment: and I use following: declare
    vCur reports.rep_type;
begin
    REPORTING_TCO.Alloc_day_graph_KTL('01-Oct-2012','30-Oct-2012', vCur);
    /* code to use the cursor */
end;
/

Comment: Please edit your question posting all your relevant code, including the structure of involved tables.

Comment: sorry Aleksej for not being clear from beginning, I just put initial code.